# Funny Joke about series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Infinitely many mathematicians walk into a bar. The first says, "I'll have a beer." The second says, "I'll have half a beer." The third says, "I'll have a quarter of a beer." The barman pulls out just two beers. The mathematicians are all like, "That's all you're giving us? How drunk do you expect us to get on that?" The bartender says, "Come on guys. Know your limits."

Comment: -1 because this is not a question. +1 because it was funny.

Comment: Though this is amusing, it's not a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: Hahaha.... this will be closed but is hilarious.

Comment: This joke is old, and only somewhat funny.  [This list](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) contains several better(*) jokes.

Comment: Might be old, but I've never heard it :)

Comment: I literally started laughing so hard in the students lab. Never came by a joke here not in the form of a degenerate, disrespectful trolling.

Comment: Aleph naught mugs of beer on the bar, aleph naught mugs of beer, take one from that, drink it down, aleph naught mugs of beer...